# Changing Drop down list ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core, dropdown

I am using ASP.NET CORE with SQL server.

I have 2 tables: `Review` and `WorkSchedule`. The `WorkSchedule` table contains `ManagerID` and `StaffID`. The `Review` table contains `ReviewerID` and `RevieweeID`. The `ManagerID`,`StaffID`,`ReviewerID`and`RevieweeID` are foreign keys to `StaffID` in the `Staff` table.

For example, if I create a new review in the `CreateReview` page, I will manually set the `ReviewerID` and `RevieweeID`. I want to make the `WorkScheduleID` dropdown to automatically change so that `WorkScheduleID` will appear where `ManagerID` = `ReviewerID` and `StaffID` = `RevieweeID`

Model:

```
namespace Starbucks.Models
{
    public class ReviewModel
    {
        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "Review ID")]
        public Guid ReviewID { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Reviewer")]
        public Guid ReviewerID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ReviewerID")]
        public StaffModel Staff { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Reviewee")]
        public Nullable<Guid> RevieweeID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("RevieweeID")]
        public StaffModel Staffs { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "WorkSchedule ID")]
        public Nullable<Guid> WorkScheduleID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("WorkScheduleID")]
        public WorkScheduleModel WorkSchedules { get; set; }
    }


    public class WorkScheduleModel
    {

        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "Work Schedule ID")]
        public Guid WorkScheduleID { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Staff ID")]
        public Nullable<Guid> StaffID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("StaffID")] 
        public StaffModel Staffs { get; set; }



        [Display(Name = "Manager ID")]
        public Guid ManagerID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ManagerID")]
        public StaffModel Staff { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateReview([Bind("ReviewID,ReviewCategoryID,ReviewRating,ReviewComment,ReviewDateTime,ReviewerID,RevieweeID,WorkScheduleID")] ReviewModel reviewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {      
                reviewModel.ReviewID = Guid.NewGuid();
                reviewModel.ReviewDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                _context.Add(reviewModel);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(ProfilePage));
            }
            ViewData["RevieweeID"] = new SelectList(_context.Staff, "StaffID", "StaffName", reviewModel.RevieweeID);
            ViewData["ReviewerID"] = new SelectList(_context.Staff, "StaffID", "StaffName", reviewModel.ReviewerID);
            ViewData["WorkScheduleID"] = new SelectList(_context.WorkSchedule, "WorkScheduleID", "WorkScheduleID");
            return View(reviewModel);
        }
```

View Page:

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <form asp-action="CreateReview">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="ReviewerID" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select asp-for="ReviewerID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ReviewerID"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="RevieweeID" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select asp-for="RevieweeID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.RevieweeID"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="WorkScheduleID" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select asp-for="WorkScheduleID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.WorkScheduleID"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method to filter the data, and use ajax to call it, then populate the select list with the returned data.

**Controller:**

```
public IActionResult Index()
{

    ViewData["RevieweeID"] = new SelectList(_context.Staff, "StaffID", "StaffName");
    ViewData["ReviewerID"] = new SelectList(_context.Staff, "StaffID", "StaffName");
    ViewData["WorkScheduleID"] = new SelectList(_context.WorkSchedule, "WorkScheduleID", "WorkScheduleID");
    return View();
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult FilterWorkScheduleID(Guid reviewerid, Guid revieweeid)
{
    var WorkScheduleIDs = _context.WorkSchedule.Where(x => x.StaffID == revieweeid && x.ManagerID == reviewerid).ToList();
    return Json(new { items = WorkScheduleIDs });
}
```

**View:**

```
@model ReviewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <form asp-action="CreateReview">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ReviewerID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="ReviewerID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ReviewerID"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="RevieweeID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="RevieweeID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.RevieweeID"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="WorkScheduleID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="WorkScheduleID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.WorkScheduleID"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts{ 
    <script>
        $("select").on("change", function () {
            var reviewerID = $("#ReviewerID").find(":selected").val();
            var revieweeID = $("#RevieweeID").find(":selected").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: '/Staff/FilterWorkScheduleID',
                data: {
                    reviewerid: reviewerID,
                    revieweeid:revieweeID
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#WorkScheduleID").empty();
                    $.each(result.items, function (i, obj) {
                        var option = "<option value=" + obj.workScheduleID + ">" + obj.workScheduleID + "</option>";
                        $(option).appendTo("#WorkScheduleID"); 
                    })
                
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
}
```

**Result:**[image]